# JSON Serialization of BitSet doesn't work

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to serialize/deserialize java.util.Bitset in JSON format.
This code:

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(10);
bs.set(1);
bs.set(5);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(System.out, bs);
```

prints *{"empty":false}* as output.
Should I write my own serializer/deserializer or is there some better way?

Comment: you need to write own serializer deserialzer

Comment: what happens when you replace your `mapper.writeValue(System.out, bs);` with `mapper.writeValueAsString(bs);`

Comment: You shouldn't have to write  (unless you want a custom format) your own as BiSet implements Serializable by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding:

```
 mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Jacksons's own [unit tests](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hppc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/hppc/ser/TestContainerSerializers.java) have ones for BitSet.  You shouldn't need to roll your own.

Comment: According to this - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-hppc/2.4.6 is a "add-on module for Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to support High-Performance Primitive Collections". I think that might be overkill for this user's use case cause they only need to an additional custom serializer, not support an additional data type

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. Please put a complete solution.

Comment: @saumilsdk - I'm not doing the work for you, just pointing you to a resource that may help.  Our job here is not to do the work for you but to guide you.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectMapper.writeValue() will look into the object class and find all getSomething methods and isSomething methods to generate json based on the methods name.

Your result {"empty":false} is come from this method of BitSet class:

```
 public boolean isEmpty() {...}
```

So I think you shoud write your own serializer/deserializer instead of using ObjectMapper serialization mechanism

Comment: I'am curious why Jackson didn't override this behavior. I doubt anybody serializing a bitset just wants the empty field written out.

Answer (score 1):

Try with custom serializer and deserializer for Bitset.

Serializer:

```
public class BitSetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BitSet> {

@Override
public void serialize(BitSet value, JsonGenerator gen,
                      SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeStartArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        gen.writeBoolean(value.get(i));
    }
    gen.writeEndArray();
}

}
```

Deserilizer:

```
public class BitSetDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<BitSet> {
@Override
public BitSet deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    BitSet ret = new BitSet();
    int i = 0;
    JsonToken token;
    while (!JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(token = jsonParser.nextValue())) {
        if (JsonToken.VALUE_TRUE.equals(token))
            ret.set(i);
        i++;
    }

    return ret;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I think, I have a solution which seems to be more space and memory saving to me - it's important due to proccessing huge amount of data. The folowing solution did it:

```
   public class BitSetSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BitSet>
    {
      @Override
      public void serialize(BitSet value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
      {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        for (long l : value.toLongArray())
        {
          gen.writeNumber(l);
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
      }

      @Override
      public Class<BitSet> handledType()
      {
        return BitSet.class;
      }
    }

    public class BitSetDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<BitSet>
    {
      @Override
      public BitSet deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
      {

        ArrayList<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>();
        JsonToken token;
        while (!JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(token = jsonParser.nextValue()))
        {
          if (token.isNumeric())
          {
            l.add(jsonParser.getLongValue());
          }
        }
        return BitSet.valueOf(Longs.toArray(l));
      }
    }

 SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule");
    testModule.addSerializer(new BitSetSerializer());
    testModule.addDeserializer(BitSet.class, new BitSetDeserializer());
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    bs.set(1);
    bs.set(1500);
    System.out.println(bs);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//    mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module()); //serialization result takes too much space 
    mapper.registerModule(testModule);

    String val = mapper.writeValueAsString(bs);
    System.out.println(val);

    BitSet bs2 = mapper.readValue(val, BitSet.class);
    System.out.println(bs2);
```

Comment: Beware that for systems which are opened to the world  this deserializer should be improved by checking a parsed value before adding it to the bitset to avoid DoS-ing using requests with Integer.MAX_VALUE numbers.